# can i build this page by woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

Hi there
is there any way too build a page like this with woocommerce? :
https://www.reyhoon.com/restaurants/shandiz-jordan

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can build it with Wordpress WooCommerce but Reyhoon is running on PHP code. But you need to understand for editing themes on Wordpress.

Wordpress has full featured plugins that you can used, but better try to code on PHP.

Only his blog running on Wordpress. I suggest you try to build it under PHP so you can customize more as you need and you can use framework like CodeIgniter or Laravel then you can use CSS framework from Bootstrap.

PHP Framework : [CodeIgniter](https://codeigniter.com/) or [Laravel](https://laravel.com/)

CSS Framework : [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)

If you still want to use Wordpress, here is the plugin for WooCommerce

Wordpress Plugin : [WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/)

Comment: i want plugin and i don't know php

Comment: Hi, what plugins you need ? If you need wordpress woocommerce plugin, I was add that link for you.

Comment: If you still have a question, you can ask it here and I will try to help.